# Flexbox fixed header, fixed left nav fluid content area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve this layout with Flexboox and Bootstrap 4:

- Fixed header on top
- Fixed left sidebar
- Fluid content area

I don't know how to make the header and sidebar fixed. Everything else works so far how I want:

HTML:

```
<header>
    header
</header>
<app>
    <nav>
        nav
    </nav>
    <article>
        Content
    </article>
</app>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header { 
    z-index: 0;
    flex: 0 64px;
    display: flex;

    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

app {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}

nav {
    background: #FAF9F8;
    flex: 0 0 256px;
    order: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

article {
    background: #F3F3F5;
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    order: 1;

    // Simulate large height
    height: 2000px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLfcL28u/203/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using flexbox like you did: http://jsfiddle.net/loic294/7hbjq82w/

The idea to make things fixed is to remove the main scrollbar in body:

```
overflow: hidden; // Removes main scrollbar to make header and nav fix
height: 100%; // Sets max height to ensure everything is fixed
```

Also add a div to make the main section scrollable:

```
<article>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</article>
```

And add this CSS to make it all work:

```
div {
   height: 2000px;
}
overflow-y: auto; // Adds scrollbar
```

Comment: Same fiddle link as mine, can you check?

Comment: Oups, yes. Here is the good link: http://jsfiddle.net/loic294/7hbjq82w/

Comment: Thanks, this works good. Unfortunately not in my actual app, it doesn't add the scrollbar for the fluid-content. Do I have to take care of anything, except adding `overflow-y: auto` and make sure the height is actually there?

Comment: You need to add a div inside the article tag and put the content inside. Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ZeTHIvo.png - check the size of the container and the html. Body has "overflow:hidden"; I am missing something but not sure what

Comment: Could you screenshot the CSS applied to `.dashboard-content` and the body inside? Also make sure the height of `.app` is 100% and has a position of relative.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Here is the requested screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ubOpMqX.png My `.app` has : `height: 100%; min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162639/discussion-between-loic-bellemare-alford-and-hresult).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use flexbox at all here, but fixed positions for the fixed elements:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #FAF9F8;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

article {
  background: #F3F3F5;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  /* Simulate large height */
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<nav>
  nav
</nav>
<article>
  Content
</article>
```